# What is the most effective way to remove epoxy plumbing putty?

Tags: plumbing, putty

At some point in the past, I used epoxy plumbing putty to seal a joint going into the faucet on my bathtub. It's now leaking again (seeping out past the putty) and I'd like to get the putty off so that I can effect a better repair.

Any good ideas? I'm thinking I may just have to chisel it off, but I'd like to not damage the faucet in the process.

Comment: Where exactly is the joint?  Can you post a pic?

Comment: if it's actual epoxy, then you likely need to replace the faucet connection completely.

Comment: It's the output from the faucet up to the showerhead. It's bolted to the back of a tub and I can't get a good pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epoxy hardens and adheres by undergoing an irreversable chemical reaction.  You won't be able to dissolve it off with anything.  You will need to cut and grind it off with a dremel tool and/or saw.

EDIT: If you used it on a metal pipe, you may have luck burning it off with a blowtorch.

Answer (score 1):

The epoxy and the metal pipe should expand and contract at different rates, so if you heat it with a torch and then cool it with water a few times you may get it to loosen up.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up chiseling the old epoxy off - it was crumblier than I'd have expected, so I suspect I mixed it wrong originally, and it came off pretty well because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:  acetone (nail polish remover) is effective on most plastics.  I'd try that first.